# Double download with WebClient.OpenReadAsync

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, webclient

Ok, in my app I need to download two lists of datas to elaborate them but I can't realize how to do it..

I click a button and then I think the downloads start almost together. This is good for me, what it's not good is that my application can't understand how to wait the downloads before doing anything else..

I know there's a design problem but I cannot figure out how to resolve it..

The code is something (more or less) like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://myRESTservice");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri); //this will set a private variableA

            dwnl();          

            doSomething(); //this will do something with A and B


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


private void dwnl()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://myRESTservice/anotherAddress");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted_B);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri); //this will set a private variableB

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope you understand the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your application is downloading the data, i.e. the OpenReadAsync method has been called you could show a busy indication. Your doSomething method would then be called from within your OpenReadCompleted event handler.
If you want one download to occur after the other has completed then you could also call the dwnl method from within your OpenReadCompleted event handler.